# How to find the points at which the edges of two polygons intersect?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find the points at which the edges of two SQL geometries (polygons) intersect - STIntersects gives me the intersecting area, but not where the edges intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because polygons represent the areas contained therein, the intersection of them will itself be an area. But, if you compute the intersection of the *boundaries*, you should get what you're looking for. To wit:

```
declare 
    @a geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0))', 0),
    @b geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1, 1 3, 3 3, 3 1, 1 1))', 0),
    @c geometry


select @c = @a.STBoundary().STIntersection(@b.STBoundary());

select @c.STPointN(n).ToString()
from Util.dbo.Numbers as n
where n.n <= @c.STNumPoints();
```

The last select is an embellishment for the purposes of demonstration. In the general case, I can't know that the intersection will be a set of points (e.g. when the two polygons share an edge, the intersection will be the shared edge).